# Cycles of length k in a complete simple graph with n vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Hello everyone interested. Here's a seemingly simple problem. 
Suppose $G$ is a complete, simple graph with vertices $\{1,2,..,n\}$, $n\geq k\geq 3$.

How many cycles of length $k$ can we have on $G$?

The statement seems simple but I have trouble putting everything together. 
So I say fix a vertex and start forming cycles with length k. But I get nowhere...
What is the proper approach to this problem since counting is not easy?
Is there a relevant theorem that I am unaware of?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Look at an example: Draw a complete graph with vertices $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Now draw a circle (usually called a *cycle*) of length $k=3$. Underline the cycle’s vertices. If you underline a different set of $k=3$ vertices, you get another cycle, right? You can find all the cycles by finding all the sets of $k$ vertices. (Since the graph is complete and simple, each of these sets defines precisely one $k$-cycle.) How many sets of $k$ vertices are there among the graph’s set of vertices $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$?

Comment: The combinations of n over k....?!?

Comment: Yes, but oops. I forgot something. While for each set of 3 vertices, there is one cycle, when it gets to 4 or more vertices, there will be more than one cycle for a given subset of vertices. For 4 vertices, there would be a “square” and a “bowtie.” If you can figure out how many cycles per $k$-subset, then you would multiply $n\choose k$ by that number. (I think this is not a trivial calculation, but not an impossible one. Vaguely?: Start a $k$-cycle anywhere, then finish it by any arrangement of the remaining $k-1$ vertices of the cycle. This counts each cycle twice (two orientations).

Comment: So the only way is to count... Thanks.

Comment: You can get Servaes’s result starting as I suggested. First, choose a subset of size $k$ (there are $n\choose k$ ways). Then choose an arbitrary starting vertex and enumerate the directed (oriented) cycles for a subset. For each $k$-subset, there are $(k-1)!$ orderings of the non-starting vertex, so that enumerates ${{n\choose k}(k-1)!}$ cycles. But you must divide by the number of times you counted each separate cycle, which is two, because you counted once for each orientation. Wrapping up, then there are $\dfrac{{n\choose k}(k-1)!}{2}=\dfrac{n!(k-1)!}{k!\cdot2(n-k)!}$ cycles of length $k$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the graph $G$ is complete, a cycle of length $k$ with a specified starting point and direction is simply an ordered $k$-tuple of distinct vertices of $G$. There are $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ such $k$-tuples, hence $\frac{1}{2k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ such cycles.

Comment: @MelaniesWoes if the factorial fraction is intimidating, consider $k=3$ - then $\frac{n!}{(n-3)!} = n(n-1)(n-2)$, representing the first, second and third choice of vertex on the cycle. Then you can go in either direction ($2$) and start at any vertex ($k$) and it still counts as the same cycle, so factor out those overcounted options ($\frac{1}{2k}$).