# How to get the following inequality: $ E[X]\le n^k p^k? $ for a Erdos-Renyi random graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G\in \mathcal{G}(n,p)$ be a Erdos-Renyi random graph. Let $X_k$ be a random variable that the number of cycles in $G$ that are length $k$. How to get the following inequality:

$$
E[X_k]\le n^k p^k?
$$

Hence, the number of cycles in $G$ that are length at most $k$, the expectation:
$$
E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^k E[X_i]\le \sum_{i=1}^k n^i p^i.
$$

---

The definition of the expectation is that
$$
E[X]=\sum_{G\in \mathcal{G}(n,p)} X(G)P(\{G\})
$$
Here for such a graph $G$, we know that $P(\{G\})=p^k$ because one cycle with length $k$.

I try to give proof as follows.

For every $k-$cycle $C$ with vertices in $V=\{0,\dots, n-1\}$. Let $X_c$ be the indicator random variable of $C$ that $X_c=1$ if $C\subset G$ otherwise 0. So
$$
E[X_c]=P(C\subset G)=p^k.
$$

But why the number of such indicator functions is at most $n^k$?

Comment: Linearity of expectation. Use one indicator variable for each potential cycle. There are at most $n^k$ indicator variables, and for each cycle, the probability that all edges appear is $p^k$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I have added these indicators. Can you please take a look? But why the number of such indicator functions is at most $n^k$?

Comment: You're just asking what the total number of $k$-cycles in the complete graph are. This has been addressed on mse previously, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772229/cycles-of-length-k-in-a-complete-simple-graph-with-n-vertices). That said, you should try to figure this out yourself. To start, can you figure out the number of $3$-cycles? As a way to progress: take a fixed set of $3$ nodes. How many $3$-cycles lie on these? How many sets of $3$ nodes are there? Multiplying these gives the total number of $3$-cycles (why?). Now try to do $4$-cycles, and then generalise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why is the number of indicators at most $n^k$?

A cycle of length $k$ is specified by an ordered list $(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k)$ of vertices. There are at most $n$ choices for each of the vertices in the list, and $k$ entries in the list, so at most $n^k$ ways to choose such a list.